# Settings environment settings for "Win-R cmd"

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

Where does one set environment settings (notice, I'm not saying just variables) that control the behaviour of cmd you get when starting with win-r? So, `Win-r` `cmd`.

Specifically, what I want to know is ... what do I need to do, if I have a bat file which I want started every time that cmd is started ... where to put it? And what to set somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

### For Microsoft's `cmd`, use `AutoRun`s.

Environment variables are irrelevant to this.  (And there's nothing aside from environment variables that is conventionally named *environment settings*, so that distinction is meaningless.)

Under the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor` (for everyone machine-wide) or the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor` (for just one user) key in the registry, add a value named `AutoRun`.  It must be a `REG_SZ` or `REG_EXPAND_SZ` value.  Microsoft's command processor will read the string every time that it starts up, and run the commands in the string before doing anything else.

### For [JP Software's TCC/LE](http://jpsoft.com./tccledes.htm) use `TCSTART.BTM`.

TCC doesn't have a local-machine-versus-per-user configuration mechanism, although it's fairly simple to achieve that with some creative use of the `%USERPROFILE%` environment variable.  There's just the one script.

### Caveat

These commands are executed by *every* instance of the command processor that you start, whether you run it from <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, or an desktop shortcut names the command processor as the program to run, or a program "shells out" by invoking the command processor to do stuff.  The local machine value will be used by any service that uses the command processor.  You can break things quite seriously, and introduce major security hazards, if you do anything non-trivial, such as commands that change directory, generate output, run external commands, or modify the filesystem, with these mechanisms.

For best results, *don't do this*.  Pass whatever you want to do in this script to the command processor on its command line, directly from the <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> edit field, instead.

### Further reading

- Microsoft corporation (2003-03-28). [*Command Processor\AutoRun*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc779439(WS.10).aspx).  TechNet.
- JP Software (2011). [*TCSTART and TCEXIT*](http://jpsoft.com/help/index.htm?autobatch.htm).  TCC On-line Help.

Comment: a) environment settings ... doskey aliases hanging in the background.

Comment: Those are not conventionally named "environment settings".

Comment: Nor did I say they were ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the `ComSpec` Environment variable to point to the batch file you want to run.

For example, setting `ComSpec` to `"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" "C:\path\to\your\batchFile.bat" /K` will cause the command prompt to run the batch file and remain open afterwards.

**NB:** You can set the Environment Variable as follows:
Right click on My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced (tab) -> Environment Variables (button)

Comment: … which has the side-effect of breaking every program that expects `COMSPEC` to point to a command processor, as it conventionally does.

Comment: well, rather unfortunately so... Your answer is better, in my opinion. I'd forgotten about that feature when I was writing my answer.